# I'm pretty confused about how to draw a hollow and rounded rectangle. How can I do this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I have a small view on a Custom TableViewCell.

The UIView is about 120 width, and 30 height. I would like to draw a hollow rectangle with rounded corners to take up basically the entire UIView, and then I will also have some subviews within this UIView like a small 20x20 UIImageView and a 20height UILabel.

How can I do this drawing?

I can draw a solid rectangle via a new UIView's layer, but I'm guessing that's not the way to do it and I should be using QuartzCore?

I tried this code below, but I'm not sure how to add it to my UIVIew?

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 22);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
```

I also tried this code, and nothing appears.

```
CAShapeLayer *rectLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[rectLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 22.0)];
[rectLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
[rectLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
[rectLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[rectLayer setLineWidth:3.0];

[[self.respondView layer] addSublayer:rectLayer];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you simply make round images and add on the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use corner radius with border color

```
yourview.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
yourview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
yourview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
yourview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Screenshot

[image]

I am not sure if this is what you want